# RequireJS - Relative path issue when loading kendo ui modules

Tags: kendo-ui, requirejs

I have the following directory structure, and the following files:

```
root
|--libs
   |--jquery
      |--jquery-1.9.1.js
   |--kendo
      |--kendo.button.min.js
      |--kendo.core.min.js
```

RequireJS Configuration is defined as below

```
require.config(
{ 
  baseUrl: 'path to root', 
  paths: 
  { 
    'jquery': 'libs/jquery/jquery-1.9.1',
    'kendo-button': 'libs/kendo/kendo.button.min'
  },
  shim:
  {
    'kendo-button': 
     {
       deps: ['jquery'] 
     }
  }
});
```

I have a module which have a dependency on 'kendo-button'

```
define(
  ['kendo-button'],
  function(kendoButton) 
  {
    ..code to create a  kendo button
  });
```

When loading this module it is throwing an error with error status 404

**script error for: kendo.core.min.**

i see that requirejs is looking for kendo.core.min.js in the root and not in the kendo folder.

*Am i doing something wrong here?*

**Note:** kendo.button.min has dependency on kendo.core.min

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the kendo.button.min.js module you will see that this module has a dependency on the kendo.core.min.js. Therefore, RequireJS will try to download this module from the location your 'path to root'/kendo.core.min.js, which leads to an 404 error. So I would modify the require.config as follows:

```
require.config(
{ 
  baseUrl: 'path to root', 
  paths: 
  { 
    'jquery': 'libs/jquery/jquery-1.9.1',
    'kendo-button': 'libs/kendo/kendo.button.min', 
    'kendo.core.min': 'libs/kendo/kendo.core.min'    
  },
  shim:
  {
    'kendo-button': 
     {
       deps: ['jquery'] 
     }
  }
});
```

As well, make sure that you copy the module kendo.core.min.js into the libs/kendo folder.

Answer (score -1):

Use Like this :

```
require.config(
{ 
  baseUrl: 'path to root', 
  paths: 
  { 
    'jquery': './libs/jquery/jquery-1.9.1',
    'kendo-button': './libs/kendo/kendo.button.min'
  },
  shim:
  {
    'kendo-button': 
     {
       deps: ['jquery'] 
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: Paths that are not absolute are already interpreted relative to `baseUrl`. Adding `./` to the start of the paths changes nothing.